# connection string in visual studio community edition

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Getting an error

> keyword not supported error

from SQL Server when I try to open a connection - I am using Visual Studio 2013 Community edition.

```
static class datastuff
{
    public static void makeconnection()
    string constr = @"data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" + @"C:\Users\leon3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\sqlserver.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open()
}
```

Comment: I guess it's `connection timeout` not connect timeout.

Comment: Use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of hardcoding the connection string, as it provides a type-safe alternative for generating the string from its components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you forget an essential part of the connection string when you want to specify a file name

```
string constr = @"data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
                  AttachDBFileName=C:\Users\leon3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\sqlserver.mdf;
                  integrated security=True;connect timeout=30";
```

Comment: yes, I forgot the AttachDBFilename.  That fixed it.

Comment: This same connection string did  not work in a VB.net program.  Turns out that in the vb program I was creating an odbcconnection as opposed to an sqlconnection. For this to work you need an sqlconnection object.

Comment: If you have an __OdbcConnection__ object then the _key=value_ pairs for the connectionstring are different. As for any other ADO.NET provider. Something to look at for help, if you have different databases or different providers, is this site [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/), while a [complete list for Sql Server could be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Your connection string is like this:

```
data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;C:\Users\leon3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\sqlserver.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30
```

That thing after the data source: `(LocalDB)\V11;` will be your source, while the database itself (the mdf file) will be just something the connection will not understand.

Maybe something like this will work:

```
string constr = @"data source=(LocalDB)\V11;" + @"AttachDbFileName=C:\Users\leon3\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\sqlserver.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30";
```